# Simplifying nested foreach loop that has if statement with one lambda expression

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, lambda

As the title specifies, I have a list of Trips a trip has a list of tickets and each ticket is connected to one customer.

I would like to compare each ticket customer id with my variable customer id to only get tickets for that one customer and also I would want to have a list of trips that this customer has tickets to.

```
   Customer customer = db.Customers.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserId.Equals(user.Id));
   List<Ticket> Tickets = new List<Ticket>();
   List<Trip> Trips = new List<Trip>();

    foreach (Trip trip in db.Trips)
    {
        trip.Tickets.ForEach(ticket =>
            {
                if (ticket.Customer.UserId == customer.UserId)
                {
                    Tickets.Add(ticket); //Add the trip to Trips
                }
            }
        );
    }
```

The code that I have in mind but can't get it to work

```
    Trips = db.Trips.Select(trip => trip.Tickets.FirstOrDefault(ticket =>
        {
            if (ticket.Customer.UserId == customer.UserId)
            {
                Tickets.Add(ticket);
            }
        })).ToList();
```

Comment: what is the problem then?

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary How could I the code that I have now replace with one lambda expression that would both create a List of trips that customer has tickets to and also add those tickets to another list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like the below should work - untested though but should get you close.

```
List<Trip> trips = db.Trips.ToList();
List<Ticket> tickets = new List<Ticket>()
trips.ForEach(p => tickets.AddRange(p.Tickets.Where(q => q.Customer.UserId == customer.UserId)));
```

Edit - if you're trying to get a list of trips for the customer and then a list of tickets I'd go about it slightly differently:

```
//get a list of customer trips
List<Trip> trips = db.Tickets.Where(p => p.Customer.UserId == customer.UserId).Select(q => q.Trip).ToList();
List<Ticket> tickets = trips.select(p => p.Tickets.Where(q => q.Customer.UserId == customer.UserId).ToList()).ToList();
//or if you're not bothered about hitting the db again:
//List<Ticket> tickets = db.Tickets.Where(p => p.Customer.UserId == customer.UserId).ToList();
```

Comment: Yeah but would it be possible to also save in the trips only the trips that this customer has tickets to, instead of using db.Trips.ToList(), I'm trying to get a list of Trips that customer went to and that customer's tickets

Comment: List<Trip> Trips = db.Trips.Select(trip => Tickets.AddRange(trip.Tickets.Where(q => q.Customer.UserId == customer.UserId))).ToList(); - This is basically what I would want to get, a list of trips that user has tickets for and add those tickets to another list

Comment: @Rick Cheers, I'm still having a slight issue with the tickets the error is cannot convert IEnumerable to Generic List, works fine with additional DB call but not when I try to reuse Trip list

Comment: Your first code get all trips unnecessarily. The second is confused, you already filtered only tickets for the customer, why do you filter it again in the `trips` object? Also, that `select` with a `where` inside of it doesn't seem to work, what is that supposed to do?

Comment: @Alisson - the question was about lamda, not the most efficient way to hit the database. And the second example gets all trips the customer has a ticket for - BUT - the trip object will still contain tickets for ALL customers - hence the filter on customer ID again.

Comment: @Higeath - try it now - I've added an additional .ToList() which is why I think you're getting that error.

Comment: @Rick it's all good, you had good intentions, it just didn't make sense to me querying `Tickets` projecting a list of `Trips` with `.Select(q => q.Trip)` then using that projected list to *project* the `Tickets` back. Maybe you just wanted to show how to do both ways...

Answer (score 1):

```
var tickets = db.Trips
    .SelectMany(trip => trip.Tickets)
    .Where(ticket => ticket.Customer.UserId == customer.UserId)
    .ToList();
```

Like that?

Answer (score 1):

To get **only the Tickets** that your customer has:

```
List<Ticket> tickets = db.Tickets
                       .Where(t => t.Customer.UserId == customer.UserId)
                       .ToList();
```

To get all the **Trips** where there is at least one ticket for your customer:

```
List<Trip> trips= db.Trips
                  .Where(t => t.Tickets.Any(ti => ti.Customer.UserId == customer.UserId))
                  .ToList();
```

However this wouldn't load tickets. If you wanted to load **trips** with their **tickets** as well, just add `Include()` like this:

```
List<Trip> trips= db.Trips.Include("Tickets")
                  .Where(t => t.Tickets.Any(ti => ti.Customer.UserId == customer.UserId))
                  .ToList();
```

> There is no need to query for **Customer**.

Comment: That last one with Include would that only include tickets of that customer to that list of Trips? Since I use lazy loading so db.Trips by default has all tickets loaded

Comment: `Include` will eager load all `Tickets` for each `Trip` in one single query. When querying without `Include`, the query will only get `Trip`, then because of the lazy load, when you try to get `Tickets` for each `Trip`, a new query will be executed to populate tickets. If you have 100 tickets and iterate over all of them, it means 100 queries would be executed for loading the Tickers of every Trip, which is very slow. If you use `Include`, they will be already populated with one single query, which is faster.

Comment: But, answering your question, it would get only **trips** where there is at least one **ticket** for your user, but the `Include` would get all tickets for those trips, including of other customers. Lazy load would do this as well. It's hard to understand what you want at all.....do you need the **Trip** object? Or do you only need the **Tickets**? If you only need Tickets, query for Tickets directly, instead of getting Trips.